# boost: thread not executing an handler posted after the reception of a signal

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I am getting acquainted with boost thread and signals. I am thus implementing this simple example, I only post the cpp file of an example class implementing a thread capable of executing a method when a Signal1 is fired. The signal is defined within a Package1Signals singleton (excuse me for these names, they have been generated from a model)

Class1.hpp

```
#ifndef CLASS1_HEADER
#define CLASS1_HEADER
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/udp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include "Package1.hpp"
#include <boost/thread.hpp>


class Class1{
private:
    boost::asio::io_service service;
public:
    boost::thread  thread;
    Class1();
    void classifierBehavior();
    void Reception1(Signal1 signal1);
    void Reception1Behavior();
};


#endif
```

Class1.cpp

```
#include "Class1.hpp"
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include "Package1.hpp"
#include "Package2.hpp"
#include "Package1.hpp"

Class1::Class1(){
 //boost::thread thread(boost::bind(&Class1::classifierBehavior,boost::ref(*this)));
 //thread.join();
 thread = boost::thread(&Class1::classifierBehavior,this);
};

void Class1::classifierBehavior(){
  Package1Signals::getInstance()->signal1.connect(boost::bind(&Class1::Reception1, 
  this,_1));
  service.run();

};

 void Class1::Reception1(Signal1 signal1){
std::cout<<"Signal received\n";
service.post(boost::bind(&Class1::Reception1Behavior, this));
 }

 void Class1::Reception1Behavior(){
std::cout<<"Behavior executed\n";
 }
```

Package1.hpp

```
#ifndef PACKAGE1_HEADER
#define PACKAGE1_HEADER
#include <boost/signal.hpp>

struct Signal1{   };

class Package1Signals{
private:
    Package1Signals();
    static Package1Signals * instance;
public:
    boost::signal<void(Signal1)> signal1;
    static Package1Signals * getInstance();
 };
 #endif
```

Package1.cpp

```
 #include "Package1.hpp"
 Package1Signals * Package1Signals::instance = NULL;
 Package1Signals::Package1Signals(){}
 Package1Signals * Package1Signals::getInstance(){
    if(!instance){
            instance = new Package1Signals();
        }
    return instance;
 }
```

here is the code which executes it

```
int main() {
    Class1 test;
    Package1Signals::getInstance()->signal1();
    test.thread.join();
    int k =0;
    std::cin>>k;
    return 0;
 }
```

I can see the thread runs, the signal is intercepted but the posted handler is not executed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your constructor blocks until the thread exits, so never reaches the next line that sends the signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can see the thread runs, the signal is intercepted

Are you sure?  I don't think the signal is event sent.

> but the posted handler is not executed. What am I doing wrong?

Your constructor creates a new thread, then waits for it to finish, so the constructor doesn't return until the new thread exits. That means this line in `main` won't execute until the receiver thread exits:

```
 Package1Signals::getInstance()->signal1();
```

Maybe you want the `boost::thread` to be a member of your class, so it has the same lifetime as your class, instead of being a local variable in the constructor.

For style considerations, you don't need to use `boost::ref(*this)` you can just pass `this`, and you don't need to use `boost:bind` to create the thread, read the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor) which tell you that constructing a `thread` with multiple arguments is equivalent to passing those arguments to `bind` and constructing the thread with the result i.e. you can just say

```
thread(&Class1::classifierBehavior, this);
```

Which is much simpler and easier to read!

**Update**: Now you've fixed the constructor so it doesn't block you have a race condition between connecting the receiver to the signal, which happens in the new thread, and publishing the signal, which happens in the main thread, as soon as the constructor finishes.  If the new thread takes a few milliseconds to start executing then it will be too late and miss the signal, because in the main thread the constructor will have finished and the signal will have been emitted already.

Try connecting the receiver *before* starting the new thread:

```
Class1::Class1(){
  Package1Signals::getInstance()->signal1.connect(boost::bind(&Class1::Reception1,   this,_1));
 thread = boost::thread(&Class1::classifierBehavior,this);
};

void Class1::classifierBehavior(){
  service.run();
};
```

This way the receiver is connected before the signal is emitted.

I *think* the `io_service` will still get the event even if the event gets posted before the service is running, but you might want to check that, otherwise there's another race condition there.

Comment: Thanks I have changed the code following your suggestions. However I guess the join in the constructor was not the only problem as it seems now neither the signal is received by the object.

Comment: You'll have to come up with a [simple self-contained complete example](http://sscce.org) then, showing the definitions of `Class1` and `Package1Signals`. Also, don't forget to call `join()` _somewhere_, maybe in the `Class1::~Class1()` destructor, otherwise the main thread will just return from `main` and the other thread will be killed, maybe before handling the signal.

Comment: I can't open your link :(.  I have posted the whole code. The signal shall not be handled by the thread but by the instance (the object containing the reference to the thread) which will then post a task to the thread. However I can't either see the cout in the signal reception. Plus I have added the join call in the main function before the cin statement. The strange thing is that I can actually input an integer from the console though I should not as the main should be blocked waiting for the thread to finish its tasks (and the thread should be in the service.run loop)

Comment: You connect to the signal in the new thread, so there's a race condition between sending the signal and connecting to receive it. What probably happens is the signal gets sent before the receiver is connected.  Try making the `connect` call before starting the new thread.

Comment: It works and thanks to your kind explanation I have understood why.

Answer (score 1):

The `thread.join();` statement basically waits till the thread exits. So what essentially happens is your constructor doesn't get completed until the thread exits, which is equivalent to running the thread code in your constructor.

The fix is to create the thread and keep the handle of it in the class. DON'T call `thread.join();` till you want to wait for the thread to finish and join the main thread.

If your thread is created to be run by `service`, you need to run the service in order for your thread to start working. So you would have to do `service.run();` in your constructor and not inside the function that is being run by the thread.

Also, if I remember it correctly, service can only be run in the same thread where it was created.

Comment: Thanks, see the correction and comment to the Jonathan answer

Comment: I have changed it the way you suggested but it does not work. However I guess it is conceptually wrong as the service.run should actually be executed in the scope of the thread that will execute the service tasks. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050588/how-in-boost-send-a-signal-in-a-thread-and-have-the-corresponding-slot-executed