# Why do we need to use boost::asio::io_service::work?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

There is an example of using boost::asio.

1. Why does this example use the boost::asio::io_service::work ?
2. And why is `srv.run ();` not called to perform tasks in the threads?

```cpp
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service srv;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(srv);
    boost::thread_group thr_grp;
    thr_grp.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &srv));
    thr_grp.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &srv));

    srv.post(boost::bind(f1, 123));
    srv.post(boost::bind(f1, 321));
    //sync

    srv.post(boost::bind(f2, 456));
    srv.post(boost::bind(f2, 654));
    //sync

    srv.stop();
    thr_grp.join();
}
```

**Update:**
What is the difference between the poll and run, when io_service is used without io_service::work?

```cpp
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service srv;
    //boost::asio::io_service::work work(srv);
    std::vector<boost::thread> thr_grp;

    srv.post(boost::bind(f1, 123));
    srv.post(boost::bind(f1, 321));
    //sync

    srv.post(boost::bind(f2, 456));
    srv.post(boost::bind(f2, 654));
    //sync

    // What is the difference between the poll and run, when io_service without work?
    thr_grp.emplace_back(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::poll, &srv));// poll or run?
    thr_grp.emplace_back(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &srv));// poll or run? 

    srv.stop();
    for(auto &i : thr_grp) i.join();

    int b;
    std::cin >> b;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When the `io_service::run` method is called without a work object, it will return right away.  Typically, that is not the behavior most developers are looking for.  There are of course some exceptions, but most developers are looking to specify a thread to handle all of the asynchronous processing and don't want that thread to exit until told to do so.  That is what your code example does.

The `io_service::run` method is specified as a delegate or function pointer in the create_thread methods.  So, when the thread is created from the `create_thread` method it will call the `io_service::run` method and it passes the `io_service` object as an argument. Typically one `io_service` object can be used with multiple socket objects.

The stop method is usually called when shutting down the application or when communication between all clients/servers is no longer required and it is not anticipated that any new connections will need to be initiated.

Comment: Thanks! But what is the difference between the poll and run, when io_service is used without io_service::work? I added second example without work. According to the external behavior in this case they(poll and run) operate at 100% identical?

Comment: Sam Miller has a pretty good answer to the difference between poll and run in his answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705411/boostasio-io-service-run-vs-poll-or-how-do-i-integrate-boostasio-in-ma)

Comment: The `work` object is deprecated. Please check on the complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56642587/3082081