# Segfault on declaring a variable of type vector<shared_ptr<int>>

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, redhat, ld

## Code

Here is the program that gives the segfault.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> y {};  

    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, there is **absolutely nothing wrong** in the program itself. The root cause of the segfault depends on the environment in which its built and ran.

---

## Background

We, at Amazon, use a build system which builds and deploys the binaries (`lib` and `bin`) in an *almost* machine independent way. For our case, that basically means it deploys the executable (built from the above program) into `$project_dir/build/bin/` and *almost* all its dependencies (i.e the shared libraries) into `$project_dir/build/lib/`. Why I used the phrase *"almost"* is because for shared libraries such `libc.so`, `libm.so`, `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` and possibly few others, the executable picks from the system (i.e from `/lib64` ). Note that it is *supposed* to pick `libstdc++` from `$project_dir/build/lib` though.

Now I run it as follows:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$project_dir/build/lib ./build/bin/run

segmentation fault
```

However if I run it, without setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. It runs fine.

---

## Diagnostics

#### 1. ldd

Here are `ldd` informations for both cases (please note that I've edited the output to mention the *full* version of the libraries *wherever there is difference*)

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$project_dir/build/lib ldd ./build/bin/run

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffce19ca000)
libstdc++.so.6 => $project_dir/build/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.20 
libgcc_s.so.1 =>  $project_dir/build/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000562ec51bc000)
```

and without LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
$ ldd ./build/bin/run

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcedde000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.16 
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.6-20110824.so.1
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560caff38000)
```

#### 2. gdb when it segfaults

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7dea45c in _dl_fixup () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.209.62.al12.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7dea45c in _dl_fixup () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#1  0x00007ffff7df0c55 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  0x00007ffff7b1dc41 in std::locale::_S_initialize() () from $project_dir/build/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7b1dc85 in std::locale::locale() () from $project_dir/build/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7b1a574 in std::ios_base::Init::Init() () from $project_dir/build/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x0000000000400fde in _GLOBAL__sub_I_main () at $project_dir/build/gcc-4.9.4/include/c++/4.9.4/iostream:74
#6  0x00000000004012ed in __libc_csu_init ()
#7  0x00007ffff7518cb0 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#8  0x0000000000401021 in _start ()
(gdb)
```

#### 3. LD_DEBUG=all

I also tried to see the linker information by enabling `LD_DEBUG=all` for the segfault case. I found something suspicious, as it searches for `pthread_once` symbol, and when it unable to find this, it gives segfault (that is my interpretation of the following output snippet BTW):

```
initialize program: $project_dir/build/bin/run

symbol=_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev;  lookup in file=$project_dir/build/bin/run [0]
symbol=_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev;  lookup in file=$project_dir/build/lib/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
binding file $project_dir/build/bin/run [0] to $project_dir/build/lib/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
symbol=_ZNSt6localeC1Ev;  lookup in file=$project_dir/build/bin/run [0]
symbol=_ZNSt6localeC1Ev;  lookup in file=$project_dir/build/lib/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
binding file $project_dir/build/lib/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to $project_dir/build/lib/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSt6localeC1Ev' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
symbol=pthread_once;  lookup in file=$project_dir/build/bin/run [0]
symbol=pthread_once;  lookup in file=$project_dir/build/lib/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
symbol=pthread_once;  lookup in file=$project_dir/build/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 [0]
symbol=pthread_once;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
symbol=pthread_once;  lookup in file=/lib64/libm.so.6 [0]
symbol=pthread_once;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
```

But I dont see any `pthread_once` for the case when it runs successfully!

---

## Questions

I know that its very difficult to debug like this and probably I've not given a lot of informations about the environments and all. But still, my question is: what could be the possible root-cause for this segfault? How to debug further and find that? Once I find the issue, fix would be easy.

---

## Compiler and Platform

I'm using **GCC 4.9** on RHEL5.

---

## Experiments

#### E#1

If I comment the following line:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> y {};
```

It compiles and runs fine!

#### E#2

I just included the following header to my program:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

and linked accordingly. Now it works without any segfault. So it seems by having a dependency on `libboost_system.so.1.53.0.`, some requirements are met, or the problem is circumvented!

#### E#3

Since I saw it working when I made the executable to be linked against `libboost_system.so.1.53.0`, so I did the following things step by step.

Instead of using `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` in the code itself, I use the original code and ran it by preloading `libboost_system.so` using `LD_PRELOAD` as follows:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=$project_dir/build/lib/libboost_system.so $project_dir/build/bin/run
```

and it ran successfully!

Next I did `ldd` on the `libboost_system.so` which gave a list of libs, two of which were:

```
  /lib64/librt.so.1
  /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

So instead of preloading `libboost_system`, I preload `librt` and `libpthread` separately:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/librt.so.1 $project_dir/build/bin/run

$ LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libpthread.so.0 $project_dir/build/bin/run
```

In both cases, it ran successfully.

Now my conclusion is that by loading either `librt` or `libpthread` (or *both* ), some requirements are met or the problem is circumvented! I still dont know the root cause of the issue, though.

---

## Compilation and Linking Options

Since the build system is complex and there are lots of options which are there by default. So I tried to explicitly add `-lpthread` using CMake's `set` command, then it worked, as we have already seen that by *preloading* `libpthread` it works!

In order to see the *build* difference between these two cases (*when-it-works* and *when-it-gives-segfault*),  I built it in *verbose* mode by passing `-v` to GCC, to see the compilation stages and the options it actually passes to `cc1plus` (compiler) and `collect2` (linker).

(*Note that paths has been edited for brevity, using dollar-sign and dummy paths.*)

> $/gcc-4.9.4/cc1plus -quiet -v -I /a/include -I /b/include -iprefix
>   $/gcc-4.9.4/     -MMD main.cpp.d -MF main.cpp.o.d -MT main.cpp.o
>   -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D __USE_XOPEN2K8     -D _LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D NDEBUG     $/lab/main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -msse -mfpmath=sse -march=core2 -auxbase-strip     main.cpp.o -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++1y -version -fdiagnostics-color=auto -ftemplate-depth=128     -fno-operator-names -o /tmp/ccxfkRyd.s

Irrespective of whether it works or not, the command-line arguments to `cc1plus` are exactly the same. No difference at all. That does not seem to be very helpful.

The difference, however, is at the linking time. Here is what I see, **for the case when it works**:

> $/gcc-4.9.4/collect2 -plugin $/gcc-4.9.4/liblto_plugin.so
>   -plugin-opt=$/gcc-4.9.4/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cchl8RtI.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -export-dynamic -dynamic-linker    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o run /usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o
>   /usr/lib/../lib64/crti.o $/gcc-4.9.4/crtbegin.o -L/a/lib -L/b/lib
>   -L/c/lib 
>   **-lpthread** --as-needed main.cpp.o    -lboost_timer -lboost_wave -lboost_chrono -lboost_filesystem -lboost_graph -lboost_locale -lboost_thread -lboost_wserialization -lboost_atomic    -lboost_context -lboost_date_time -lboost_iostreams -lboost_math_c99 -lboost_math_c99f -lboost_math_c99l -lboost_math_tr1 -lboost_math_tr1f    -lboost_math_tr1l -lboost_mpi -lboost_prg_exec_monitor -lboost_program_options -lboost_random -lboost_regex -lboost_serialization -lboost_signals    -lboost_system -lboost_unit_test_framework -lboost_exception -lboost_test_exec_monitor -lbz2 -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lz     -rpath /a/lib:/b/lib:/c/lib: -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc **-lpthread** -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc $/gcc-4.9.4/crtend.o /usr/lib/../lib64/crtn.o

As you can see, `-lpthread` is mentioned **twice**! The first `-lpthread` (which is followed by `--as-needed`) is *missing* **for the case when it gives segfault**. That is the *only* difference between these two cases.

---

## Output of `nm -C` in both cases

Interestingly, the output of `nm -C` in both cases is identical (*if you ignore the integer values in the first columns*).

```
0000000000402580 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000402798 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000401000 t _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
0000000000401358 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
                 U _Unwind_Resume
0000000000401150 W std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy()
0000000000401170 W std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<int> > >::~vector()
0000000000401170 W std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<int> > >::~vector()
0000000000401250 W std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > > >::~vector()
0000000000401250 W std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > > >::~vector()
                 U std::ios_base::Init::Init()
                 U std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
0000000000402880 B std::cout
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
0000000000402841 b std::__ioinit
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
                 U operator delete(void*)
                 U operator new(unsigned long)
0000000000401510 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000402818 d __JCR_END__
0000000000402818 d __JCR_LIST__
0000000000402820 d __TMC_END__
0000000000402820 d __TMC_LIST__
0000000000402838 A __bss_start
                 U __cxa_atexit
0000000000402808 D __data_start
0000000000401100 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000402820 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000402810 d __dso_handle
0000000000402828 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
                 w __gmon_start__
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
0000000000402838 t __init_array_end
0000000000402828 t __init_array_start
00000000004012b0 T __libc_csu_fini
00000000004012c0 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main
                 w __pthread_key_create
0000000000402838 A _edata
0000000000402990 A _end
000000000040134c T _fini
0000000000400e68 T _init
0000000000401028 T _start
0000000000401054 t call_gmon_start
0000000000402840 b completed.6661
0000000000402808 W data_start
0000000000401080 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000401120 t frame_dummy
0000000000400f40 T main
00000000004010c0 t register_tm_clones
```

Comment: From a C++ perspective it looks like UB due to ODR violation. The symbols of the standard library that was used during compilation must match those during linking, which seems to sometimes not be the case here. Just recompiling on the target machine should fix this. If you cannot do that check which library versions are binary compatible and make sure the target machine has and uses such a version. Alternatively you can try to statically link some of the libraries instead of using dynamic linking, but you probably can't do that for everything.

Comment: Just some random thoughts: `pthread_once` is in `libthread`. If do you compile your program with `-pthread` option, it solves the problem? You said that including `libboost_system.so.1.53.0` solved your problem, but notice that `libboost_system.so.1.53.0` is linked against `libpthread`. From the trace you provide, `build/private/builds/RelWithDebInfo/runpools` is in the list of searchable files. Question: `runpools` needs to be linked with `libphtreads`?

Comment: @Amadeus: I do compile my code with `-pthread` (which is by default, in the build setttings, which I inherit). However,  since my code doesn't use  any *symbol* from `libpthread`, the linker doesn't add it to the executable. Also,  the *search* for `pthread_once` in the LD_DEBUG output seems to be red-herring, as it is not there when it runs successfully. That means, it is not even needed. (`runpools` path should be `$project_dir/build/bin/run` btw; edited the question).

Comment: Possibly your C++ compiler was not built against the same libc that now exists?

Comment: It's bizarre that including boost fixes anything, my experience is the opposite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948997/use-of-boost-log-and-boost-asio-causes-a-crash. Your problem is likely to be due to conflicting build options

Comment: @James: "*conflicting build options*" is one possibility that I'm a victim of.. However, the build system is so complex and it inherits many flags by default, that could cause the issue. I'd try to post the *options* though, when I'm in office (on Monday)!

Comment: I guess giving up the idea of building "in an almost machine independent way" or linking everything statically (go-lang-style) is not an option?

Comment: @VTT: Neither is the option in *production*; though I might experiment with static linking!!

Comment: this might be related to the way gcc's libstdc++ links against pthread to optimize for single threaded apps, eg. see [this](http://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2014/10/18/5) (you may try the code snippet (or some variant) at the end of the linked post)

Comment: Just some random thoughts: `pthread_once` is needed by the initialization of a static variable, probably needed by `locale`. This is part of the C++11 language support, it can be disabled/enabled with `-f(no)threadsafe-statics`.

Comment: Could you provide the output of `nm myprog` in both cases?

Comment: @sbabbi: Posted (see the last section). It is identical, ignoring the values in the first column!

Comment: Any chance you are using the gold linker? This [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16417) looks suspiciously similar...

Comment: How would I know if I'm using it or not? Any approach to find that? The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)) talks about the option `-fuse-ld=gold` which is passed to GCC to use *gold*. But I'm not using that. Any other approach?

Comment: Well, it looks like `gcc 4.9.4` by default uses `gold` linker instead of `bfd` linker (at least my complex settings do that, though its not passed as command-line, as we can see). So I decided to explicitly pass `bfd` to the linker as `-Wl,-fuse-ld=bfd` **and it worked**. NO SEGFAULT. and the `ldd` commands lists `pthread.so` as well.

Comment: I think we've nailed it. Now the question is, why does it use `gold` by default?  And why does `gold` not add `pthread.so` dependency to the binary if it is *needed*? Why do I need to mention `-pthread` and `-lpthread` both? (`-pthread` is passed by default by our build system, and I've pass `-lpthread` to make it work with `gold` is used).

Comment: Also, when I comment `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>` in my code, then `__pthread_key_create` is missing from `nm -C` output and the code works (as expected), even though `pthread.so` is *not* listed under `ldd`.

Comment: My buildsystem indeed uses `ld.gold` by default, as on my system `ld` is a softlink that points to `ld.gold`.  Awesome finding/guess @sbabbi. Thanks. Though my questions remain same (as posted in the previous comments), as it is much more relevant now .

Comment: @Nawaz See second edit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given the point of crash, and the fact that preloading `libpthread` seems to fix it, I believe that the execution of the two cases diverges at [`locale_init.cc:315`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/locale_init.cc). Here is an extract of the code:

```
  void
  locale::_S_initialize()
  {
#ifdef __GTHREADS
    if (__gthread_active_p())
      __gthread_once(&_S_once, _S_initialize_once);
#endif
    if (!_S_classic)
      _S_initialize_once();
  }
```

`__gthread_active_p()` returns true if your program is linked against pthread, specifically it checks if `pthread_key_create` is available. On my system, this symbol is defined in "/usr/include/c++/7.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h" as `static inline`, hence it is a potential source of ODR violation.

Notice that `LD_PRELOAD=libpthread,so` will always cause `__gthread_active_p()` to return true.

`__gthread_once` is another inlined symbol that should always forward to `pthread_once`.

It's hard to guess what's going on without debugging, but I suspect that you are hitting the true branch of `__gthread_active_p()` even when it shouldn't, and the program then crashes because there is no `pthread_once` to call.

**EDIT**:
So I did some experiments, the only way I see to get a crash in `std::locale::_S_initialize` is if `__gthread_active_p` returns true, but `pthread_once` is not linked in.

libstdc++ does not link directly against `pthread`, but it imports half of `pthread_xx` as weak objects, which means they can be undefined and not cause a linker error.

Obviously linking pthread will make the crash disappear, but if I am right, the main issue is that your `libstdc++` thinks that it is inside a multi-threaded executable even if we did not link pthread in.

Now, `__gthread_active_p` uses `__pthread_key_create` to decide if we have threads or no. This is defined in your executable as a weak object (can be nullptr and still be fine). I am 99% sure that the symbol is there because of `shared_ptr` (remove it and check `nm` again to be sure).
So, somehow `__pthread_key_create` gets bound to a valid address, maybe because of that last `-lpthread` in your linker flags.
You can verify this theory by putting a breakpoint at `locale_init.cc:315` and checking which branch you take.

**EDIT2**:

Summary of the comments, the issue is only reproducible if we have all of the following:

1. Use `ld.gold` instead of `ld.bfd`
2. Use `--as-needed`
3. Forcing a weak definition of `__pthread_key_create`, in this case via instantiation of `std::shared_ptr`.
4. Not linking to `pthread`, or linking `pthread` **after** `--as-needed`.

To answer the questions in the comments:

> Why does it use gold by default?

By default it uses `/usr/bin/ld`, which on most distro is a symlink to either `/usr/bin/ld.bfd` or `/usr/bin/ld.gold`. Such default can be manipulated using `update-alternatives`. I am not sure why in your case it is `ld.gold`, as far as I understand RHEL5 ships with `ld.bfd` as default.

> And why does gold not add pthread.so dependency to the binary if it is needed?

Because the definition of what is needed is somehow shady. `man ld` says (emphasis mine):

> --as-needed
>
> --no-as-needed
>
> This option affects ELF DT_NEEDED tags for dynamic libraries mentioned on the command line **after the --as-needed option.**
>   Normally the linker will add a DT_NEEDED
>              tag for each dynamic library mentioned on the command line, regardless of whether the library is actually needed or not. 
>   --as-needed causes a DT_NEEDED tag to
>              only be emitted for a library that at that point in the link satisfies a **non-weak undefined symbol** reference from a regular
>   object file or, if the library is not
>              found in the DT_NEEDED lists of other needed libraries, a non-weak undefined symbol reference from another needed dynamic
>   library.  Object files or libraries
>              appearing on the command line after the library in question do not affect whether the library is seen as needed.  This is similar
>   to the rules for extraction of
>              object files from archives.  --no-as-needed restores the default behaviour.

Now, according to [this bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16417), `gold` is honoring the "non weak undefined symbol" part, while `ld.bfd` sees weak symbols as needed. TBH I do not have a full understanding on this, and there is some discussion on that link as to whether this is to be considered a `ld.gold` bug, or a `libstdc++` bug.

> Why do I need to mention -pthread and -lpthread both? (-pthread is
>   passed by default by our build system, and I've pass -lpthread to make
>   it work with gold is used).

`-pthread` and `-lpthread` do different things (see [pthread vs lpthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling)). It is my understanding that the former should imply the latter.

Regardless, you can probably pass `-lpthread` only once, but you need to do it *before* `--as-needed`, or use `--no-as-needed` after the last library and before `-lpthread`.

It is also worth mentioning that I was not able to reproduce this issue on my system (GCC 7.2), even using the gold linker.
So I suspect that it has been fixed in a more recent version libstdc++, which might also explain why it does not segfault if you use the system standard library.

Comment: Is `__gthread_once` and `pthread_once` same? They seem to be different APIs. The former seems to be defined in `libgcc`, whereas the latter in `libpthread`.

Comment: *"`__gthread_once` is another inlined symbol that should always forward to `pthread_once`."*... Is it documented?

Comment: @Nawaz [ghtr-posix.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/gthr-posix.h):696. But it could also be [gthr-single.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/gthr-single.h), depending on some config.

Comment: Have added *Compilation and Linking Options* to the question. Please see it!

Comment: The edit makes sense on all points. Looks like a bug in `libstdc++ (gcc 4.9.4)`. On my system (gcc.4.9.4), I did `nm -C libstdc++.so.6.0.20 | grep pthread` and it listed all symbols as `w`. Can you do the same on your system (gcc 7.2) and see what it lists?

Comment: @Nawaz also in my system all the symbols are listed as `w`.

Comment: Yes. I thought so. Just wondering in what ways `libstdc++` could be at fault.  Is it not checking the existence of a definition before using it? Something like `if(__pthread_key_create) __pthread_key_create(args); else do_alternative();`  (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15525956/415784))?

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, it does something like that. But there is a build flag for libstdc++ called `GTHREAD_USE_WEAK`, if this is defined to 0 the check is apparently removed.
I would expect that in this case the resulting `libstdc++` should explicitly link against `pthread`. I am going to try to build libstdc++ without that flag and see what happens.

Comment: I replaced `std::shared_ptr` line with `std::cout << ::__gthread_active_p() << std::endl;`, and it results in the segfault with the same stacktrace in the *gdb*... that means the problem is in `__gthread_active_p()` .

Answer (score 9):

This is likely a problem caused by subtle mismatches between `libstdc++` ABIs. GCC 4.9 is not the system compiler on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5, so it's not quite clear what you are using there (DTS 3?).

The locale implementation is known to be quite sensitive to ABI mismatches.  See this thread on the gcc-help list:

- [Binary compatibility between an old static libstdc++ and a new dynamic one](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2017-04/msg00062.html)
- [plus follow-ups in the next month](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2017-05/msg00164.html)

Your best bet is to figure out which bits of `libstdc++` where linked where, and somehow achieve consistency (either by hiding symbols, or recompiling things so that they are compatible).

It may also be useful to investigate the hybrid linkage model used for `libstdc++` in Red Hat's Developer Toolset (where newer bits are linked statically, but the bulk of the C++ standard library uses the existing system DSO), but the system `libstdc++` in Red hat Enterprise Linux 5 might be too old for that if you need support for current language features.

Comment: What do you mean by *"GCC 4.9 is not the system compiler on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5"*? You meant `GCC 4.9` is not built for `RHEL5` and thus it may not work there properly? Could you please elaborate on that a bit more, as it seems to be an important point?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux came with GCC 4.1 initially, with GCC 4.4 as an option (in the form of the `gcc44` package). This is not *that* important, but it suggests that you might run into ABI issues because you use multiple compilers which have not been built in such a way that they build compatible binaries.

Comment: Have added *Compilation and Linking Options* to the question. Please see it!