# In which thread are the slots executed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-signals2

Suppose I have four threads, with the following objects:

Thread 1: manages a `boost::signals2` object. Call it `s`.

Thread 2: manages a `X` object and a reference to `s`. Call the `X` object `o2`. The member function `X::do()` is connected to `s`, to be executed over `o2`.

Thread 3: manages a `Y` object and a reference to `s`. Call the `Y` object `o3`. The member function `Y::do()` is connected to `s`, to be executed over `o3`.

Thread 4: manages a reference to `s`, and `emit`s the signal.

Where are the slots executed? All of them in thread 4, where the `emit` call took place? Over thread 1, because that's the thread of the signal's memory address? Or each slot is executed on its corresponding thread (2 and 3)?

The most obvious thing is the slots are executed over `thread 4`, because there was were the signal was emitted (and the calls are synchonous), but it seems very weird to me a thread executing a function, or in general, manipulating an object, whose memory address belongs to another thread (for example, an object created on the heap of a thread, but being used in a different one).

Are the access to "foreigns" threads, at least, slower than just manipulating "my own" objects, or are there no differences at all?

Comment: Unlike Qt's implementation of signals and slots, `boost::signals2` doesn't come with any sort of message loop so it can't post work to another thread. Slots are executed on the thread that emits the signal. If you do want a particular slot to run on another thread, you'll need some sort of work queue. [`boost::asio`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5106187/1020072) is probably a good choice.

Comment: Memory isn't _owned_ by any particular thread. Any given thread has no problem accessing another thread's stack, or an object on the heap that was allocated by another thread. This shared memory space is what can make threading difficult as it opens you up to the terrors of [data races](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software).

Comment: @SeanCline If your comment were an answer, I would select it as the valid answer.

Comment: @SeanCline https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage isn't that "owned" by a thread?

Comment: I would say a `thread_local` variable is just a global variable, but with a different memory address for each thread (so, each `thread_local` variable name binds to a different memory address in each thread). I think you can pass yet that address (through a pointer or reference), to another thread. So, a thread could manipulate a foreign's `thread_local` variable.

Comment: @xaxxon Adding to Peregring-lk's response... It's up to the compiler/platform how it wants to implement TLS. At a high level, it's just a base address that's stored with each thread. When accessing a TLS variable, the per-thread base address is added to the offset of the variable that's being accessed. The memory still lives in the same virtual address space as all other memory in the process and _could_ be shared with another thread. That said, please never do that. It's confusing. (Also, TLS should probably be avoided in most cases, if only for its performance cost.)

Answer (score 0):

Slots are invoked serially on the thread that invoked (emitted) the signal. For simplicity, you could think of signlas as simply a list of slots. Once a a signal is being invoked by some thread, it is as if that thread iterated on that list and invoked each connected slot.

Refering to your second question, a thread doesn't really 'own' what was allocated from it. Memory and object ownership is something you determine according to the way you manage your code. In general, any thread may access any memory address on its process memory space as long as you manage to pass it a valid address to that location.