# Solutions to replace Qt's signal-slot connections (across thread boundaries)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

In Qt one can:

```
connect(object, &Object::someSignal, objectInAnotherThread, &Object::someSlot);
```

So, when I connect a signal from an object in a thread to an object in another thread, Qt queues the signal and someSlot will be executed **in the thread of objectInAnotherThread**.

This particular feature is very handy and safe, although could copy data.

Lambdas in C++11 are handy, but when replacing this kind of connection with a pure lambda callback (without Qt), the lambda will be executed **in the thread of the caller**. This will then usually require mutexes etc error-prone logic to make things right.

I'm aware of `Boost::signals2` etc, but AFAIK they don't provide this same Qt-like behavior when used across thread boundaries..?

If I'd like to remove Qt for a reason or another, what are my options for drop-in replacement regarding my signal-slot connections?

Comment: Small correction to your question but not an answer: If you use the `QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject *context, Functor functor)` signature, the lambda is executed in the owning thread of `context`.

Comment: Have you noticed this?: [QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject *context, Functor functor, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5)

Comment: Clarification: this was not about using C++11 lambdas with Qt but remove Qt signals and slot altogether and replace with something else. Maybe my original text was a bit misleading.

Comment: This thread has some suggestions but no accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757937/safe-cross-thread-signals-slot-c

Answer (score 0):

What’s wrong with spinning up a thread and sending wrapped function calls to a queue that the thread pulls from and executes? The event queue in Qt is not very special other than it uses the “native” event loop. There’s no need to do that, though, and e.g. QtConcurrent::run threads implement a simple mutex+wait condition protected queue. Whenever the new events are delivered, the thread gets woken up and processes them until the queue is empty. The events can carry functor calls. In fact, the events can simply be std::function. The only sticking point is timers, which you’d have to implement on top of the primitive that waits on the wait condition. Those waits have timeouts, and you’d use a sorted timeout queue and schedule wake ups whenever a timer object should “tick”. This has the benefit of not using up any native timers and can potentially perform better.